# Docusign Countersignature Automation

Tags: docusignapi, docusignapextoolkit, docusign-sdk

Is there any documentation on how to automate countersignature with docusign? I've seen contradictory comments on whether this can be done. I have spoken with some people who send out a high volume of documents that essentially need to be "rubber stamped" when they come back with signature. How has this been accomplished elsewhere?

It looks like this was possible in the on-prem docusign product that is being deprecated: https://support.docusign.com/s/articles/DocuSign-Signature-Appliance-Depreciation-FAQ?language=en_US

Comment: Does it matter who signs first? the human or the countersign? If it doesn't, maybe there's a way....

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, only the DocuSign signature appliance supported programmatic signing.

You can enter an enhancement request with your DocuSign salesperson